# Как прервать цикл при введении отрицательного числа?

Tags: c++, циклы

А вот как реализовать условие выхода (ввод отрицательного значения при вводе оценки) из цикла, но так чтобы это введенное отрицательное значение не отражалось на расчете на средней оценке ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::cout << "Math's score' " << i+1 << ": ";
    std::cin >> scores[i];
    if(scores[i]<0)
    break;

    sum += scores[i];
}

student.set_scores(scores);
float average_ball = sum / 5.0;
```

Comment: у вас и так прерван цикл, потому что у вас n имеет значение нулевое

Comment: Я знаю. Поэтому и спрашиваю как бы реализовать ввод оценок таким образом, чтобы они вводились до тех пор пока пользователь не ввел отрицательное число чтобы выйти из цикла. НУ и потом высчитывалась средняя оценка по количеству их введенных

Comment: не нужно вводить изменения в вопросе после ответов

Answer (score 3):

```
int n=0;
```

Это не хорошо. Настоящий цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

тогда не выполняется ни один раз, так как для `i = 0` не будет исполнено условие `i < n`. Измените его например на

```
int n = 100;
```

Дальше, часть

```
    if(n<0)
    break;
```

бесполезная, так как `n<0` никогда не наступит. Устраните ее.

Тестирование на отрицательность ввода будет наследовать после строки

```
std::cin >> scores[i];
```

и может иметь вид

```
if (scores[i] < 0)
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на **изменен** вопрос (не хорошо изменять вопрос после ответа, потому что другие люди не будут видеть связь между вопросом и ответом):

Все в порядке, так как команда

```
sum += scores[i];
```

после команды

```
break;
```

уже не выполнится. Единая правка в числе оценок - оно автоматически сохранено в переменной `i` после окончания цикла.

И так вместо

```
float average_ball = sum / 5.0;
```

используйте команду

```
float average_ball = sum / i;      // переменная i сохранила значение из предыдущего цикла
```

или - когда `sum` определена как `int`

```
float average_ball = float(sum) / i;
```